# Как блокировать OnMouseEnter когда мышка находится на UI

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Привет, Как блокировать OnMouseEnter когда мышка находится на UI? Пробовал EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject () - но не пашет вроде. На камере PhysicsRaycaster не установлен.

Comment: Подробнее опишите задачу. Что значит блокировать OnMouseEnter?

Comment: на OnMouseEnter у меня меняется цвет 3d объекта. В приложении есть ui (панель + кнопки). Так вот, когда я мышкой нахожусь на элементах ui, я не хочу чтобы менялся цвет у объекта.

Comment: Элементы UI являются дочерними для Canvas?

Comment: Да. Есть один канвас. Дочерними объектами являются несколько панелей, на которых размещены кнопки.

Comment: EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() очень даже пашет. Специально только что проверил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() - вполне рабочий способ решить проблему. Только что специально проверил, на всякий случай :)
IsPointerOverGameObject() возвращает переменную булевого типа, указывающую находится ли указатель над хотя бы одним объектом EventSystem.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убираем у Panel галочку "Raycast Target", иначе (если панель растянута на весь экран) курсор всегда будет определятся как над UI объектом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кидаем на наш 3d GameObject (в данном случае куб) такой скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    Material cube;
    [SerializeField] Color colorDefault;
    [SerializeField] Color colorSelect;

    private void Start()
    {
        cube = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        cube.color = colorDefault;
    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {        
        if(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            return;

        cube.color = colorSelect; 
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        cube.color = colorDefault;
    }

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())          
            cube.color = colorDefault;
    }

}
```

Имеем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь при наведении курсора на куб цвет сменится. Когда перевести курсор с куба на на кнопку, будет установлен цвет по умолчанию. При наведении курсора сразу на кнопку, цвет куба останется по умолчанию.

Скриншоты программы "в работе" не кидаю, так как курсор, все равно, не попадает на PrintScreen. Но сама сцена вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое) Работает)